# Why is hive writing 2 part files to hdfs even though number of mappers and reducers is set to 1

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a hive insert overwrite query - `set mapred.map.tasks=1; set mapred.reduce.tasks=1; insert overwrite table staging.table1 partition(dt) select * from testing.table1;`

When I inspect the HDFS directory for staging.table1, I see that there are 2 part files created.

```
2019-12-25 02:25 /data/staging/table1/dt=2019-12-24/000000_0
2019-12-25 02:25 /data/staging/table1/dt=2019-12-24/000001_0
```

Why is it that 2 files are created?

I am using beeline client and hive 2.1.1-cdh6.3.1

Comment: All `mapred.*` properties are deprecated, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `insert` query you executed is map-only, which means there is no reduce task. So there's no point of setting `mapred.reduce.tasks`.

Also, the number of mapper is determined by the num of splits, so setting `mapred.map.tasks` won't change the parallelism of mappers.

There are at least two feasible ways to enforce the resultant num of files to be 1:

1. Enforcing a post job for file merging.
   Set `hive.merge.mapfiles` to be true. Well, the default value is already true.
   Decrease `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize` to actually trigger the merging.
   Increase `hive.merge.size.per.task` to be big enough as the target size after merging.
2. Configuring the file merging behavior of mappers to cut down num of mappers.
   Make sure that `hive.input.format` is set to  `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat`, which is also the default.
   Then increase `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` to allow larger split size.