# Hive (1.1.0) - Getting small files while loading data to RC table with dynamic partition

Tags: hive, hiveql, cloudera

I'm using `insert into` command to load data from txt table to RC table.
The destination table (RC) is partitioned table, therefore, the dynamic partition is enabled. At the end of the `insert into` command I have multiple small files in each partition... I tried to set few Hive parameters for merge, but the result is more or less the same...

The only thing that worked for me is when I added `order by [any column]` to `insert into` command In that case, there is a reduce process which cause to have eventually a single file in each partition.

This is like ugly workaround, I'm looking for a more elegant way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Which parameters have you tried? Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/59496778/12602787

Comment: Thank you, I tried most of the parameters suggested in the link you shared. Any idea which value need to be configured ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DISTRIBUTE BY <partition key(list)>` instead of `ORDER BY`, it will group data by partition key and final reducers will process single partition each instead of writing each partition files per reducer process and will work faster than `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I’ll try that. The question whether distributed by will cause a reduce job

Comment: @sharon Yes it will trigger reduce step.

Comment: @sharon Read also about MERGE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52038126/2700344